# How to get a URL from python 'webbrowser'?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, firefox, python-webbrowser

I'm using 'webbrowser' for opening multiple tabs in Chrome/Firefox.
For example:

```
webbrowser.get("open -a /Applications/Firefox.app %s").open('http://google.com',new=1)
```

But the problem is, in somecases, the url gets changed(may be redirected to captcha provider), then I have to stop opening new tabs and terminate. Is there any way to read the URL after opening it using 'webbrowser'?

Here, 'Selenium' doesn't help me, because I need some extensions to be installed in the browser and I have to provide my login details and configure some settings in that extensions/plugins. So, I don't think selenium webdriver will be useful here.

Can you suggest any solution for this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Did you try using selenium?

Comment: Yes, I already mentioned that in the question. It will only get complex with Selenium because of the extensions/plugins installation along with the login details and additional configurations.

Answer (score 0):

if I understood your question well, you want to open the link each time in the browser, if that's the case you could use

```
webbrowser.open_new_tab("link")
```

Comment: Sorry! But that's not my question. My question is: how to get that "link" from the webbrowser?